# case_when(): How to add a warning message if all conditions are met in the first statement

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

Consider this example data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, Day = c(0L, 0L, 0L), baseline = structure(c(0.78, 
0.92, 1.09), names = c("", "", "")), day_1_2_value = structure(c(1.24, 
1.62, 2.41), names = c("", "", "")), day_3_7_value = structure(c(1.08, 
2.07, 5.64), names = c("", "", ""))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

     id   Day baseline day_1_2_value day_3_7_value
  <int> <int>    <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1     0     0.78          1.24          1.08
2     2     0     0.92          1.62          2.07
3     3     0     1.09          2.41          5.64
```

I want to use case_when with these conditions:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 mutate(akin_stage = case_when(
  day_3_7_value >= baseline * 1.5 & day_3_7_value <= baseline * 1.9 | 
  day_3_7_value >= baseline + 0.3 ~ "Stage 1",
  day_3_7_value >= baseline * 2.0 & day_3_7_value < baseline * 3.0 ~ "Stage 2",
  day_3_7_value >= baseline * 3.0 ~ "Stage 3"))
```

output:

```
     id   Day baseline day_1_2_value day_3_7_value akin_stage
  <int> <int>    <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>     
1     1     0     0.78          1.24          1.08 Stage 1   
2     2     0     0.92          1.62          2.07 Stage 1   
3     3     0     1.09          2.41          5.64 Stage 1
```

But the correct output would be:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 mutate(akin_stage = case_when(
  day_3_7_value >= baseline * 3.0 ~ "Stage 3",
  day_3_7_value >= baseline * 2.0 & day_3_7_value < baseline * 3.0 ~ "Stage 2",
  day_3_7_value >= baseline * 1.5 & day_3_7_value <= baseline * 1.9 | 
  day_3_7_value >= baseline + 0.3 ~ "Stage 1"
))
```

output:

```
    id   Day baseline day_1_2_value day_3_7_value akin_stage
  <int> <int>    <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>     
1     1     0     0.78          1.24          1.08 Stage 1   
2     2     0     0.92          1.62          2.07 Stage 2   
3     3     0     1.09          2.41          5.64 Stage 3
```

As you can observe, rearranging the order of the conditions provides the correct solution. This is because, in the initial solution, all conditions are satisfied with 'Stage 1,' and as a result, the subsequent conditions are not triggered.

Therefore, is there a need for a warning in `case_when()` if all conditions are satisfied in the first condition?

How could we implement such a "warning" or "note"?

Comment: I suppose you could check if all of the first condition vector evaluates to TRUE, and if so give a`warning()` or `message()`

Comment: but I don't see a need for this, either everything is meant to be put into the first category, or they seem not to understand how case_when works - it goes with the first one which is TRUE, so you go from the least common/hardest to satisfy category to the easiest/most common category. But the source code can be seen running `case_when`, so it wouldn't be too hard to even create a new function which did this check, if you were wanting something more permanent

Comment: ^ right, I think the attraction of case_when is its concision -- I like that I don't have to make my cases mutually exclusive. If you want to know all the tests that pass, perhaps something like `akin_stage = paste0(if_else(test1, "test1",""), if_else(test2, "test2",""))` would be more useful?